# Is there a keyboard shortcut for 4x6 crop in Lightroom 4, or way to set a default aspect ratio?

Tags: lightroom, cropping, lightroom-4, keyboard-shortcuts

I spend a lot of time cropping photos into the 4x6 aspect ratio in order for friends and family to get prints.

When I switch to the crop tool, Lightroom always starts with an unlocked, "Original" aspect ratio, and I have to manually switch it to 4x6.

Is there a way to get LR4 to assume I want 4x6 every time I crop?  Failing that, is there a keyboard shortcut (or a series of them) that I can use to quickly get into 4x6 crop mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Lightroom 4 Missing FAQ](http://www.lightroomqueen.com/books/adobe-lightroom-4-missing-faq/) says that you can't change the default crop ratio but you can crop multiple images at the same time by either selecting them in grid view and cropping via the quick develop panel (which centres the crop on the centre of the original image) or by cropping one image and then synchronising the others (which places the crop in the same location for all images). If you need each image to be cropped differently you still need to adjust every image manually.

The are unfortunately no keyboard shortcuts to choose a specific crop ratio other than the original.

Comment: Thanks for the FAQ link.  Bummer on the answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

After cropping the first photo to the ratio of your choice and switching to the next photo - type **Shift-A** to get into the crop tool with the same aspect ratio as last used.

Comment: Shift-A usually works fine, but sometime Lr4 "forgets" about that pre-set :(